# If Linear equations solution is inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

If my Linear equation system's martix is inconsistent.

There is no point to check homogenus system's solution, and I can safely say that the asked system has no solutions. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The nonhomogeneous system would have no solution in this case. The homogeneous system would have infinitely many solutions. If the question doesn't ask you about the homogeneous system, you can safely say it has no solutions.

Comment: Well I have to write the general solution. So in this case there would not be any solutions?

Comment: @confusedstudent: If you are asked to find the solution of an inconsistent nonhomogeneous system, then the answer is no solution. However I am not sure if that's what you are asking. If you could write down the system, it would be easier for me to answer.